# What is the simplest way of using isdigit() and isalpha() commands?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, stdio

I need a brief explanation on how the two commands `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` work. Of course, I read online sources before asking the question, but I tried them and couldn't get them to work. What is the simplest way of using them?

I know it gives back a value, so I'm assuming I can use it like this:

```
if(isdigit(someinput)==1)
 return -1;
```

Is that correct? Can I use this for any type of character? And can I compare it with a float number or array?

Suppose, I want to scanf a text file that has numbers and letter and determine what I'm scanning. Can these two commands be used in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not "commands", they are functions.  Functions accept arguments and return values.

```
#include <ctype.h>
int isdigit( int ch );
```

This is the signature for the `isdigit` function: it indicates that it will accept an `int` value (or something that can be cast to `int`, like a `char`), and will return an `int`.  You cannot, therefore, pass it an array (though you can call it on every member of an `int[]`).

The signature for `isalpha` is identical (except for the name, obviously).

The documentation says the following:

> Description: The function isalpha()
>   returns non-zero if its argument is a
>   letter of the alphabet. Otherwise,
>   zero is returned.

This means your comparison will not be correct for all implementations.  Better to do something like:

```
if (isdigit(someinput)) {
 return -1;
}
```

In C, 0 will evaluate to `false` in a boolean expression, and all non-zero values evaluate to `true`.  So this check will cover implementations of `isdigit` that return -1, 5, whatever.

If you want to apply these to values in a text file, you must read the text one character at a time and pass the characters you receive to those methods.

Comment: Thanks ! So I can only use this to compare a single character ?

Comment: One invocation of this function will take a single character, but of course you can repeat as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for replying, one final offtopic question...What is the method to convert a character to a number ?

Comment: If you want to get the ascii code of a `char`, just cast it to an `int`.  If you want to convert from the character `'5'` to the integer value 5, you can do `'5' - '0'` (this will subtract the ascii value of `'0'` from that of `'5'`; the difference will be `5`).

Comment: *it indicates that it will accept an int value (or something that can be cast to int, like a char),*: I'm afraid that's incorrect, the `isxxx()` functions defined in `<ctype.h>` take an `int` argument but are only defined for a restricted range of this type: the valid argument values are all values of type `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF`. Passing a `char` on an architecture where `char` is signed by default would invoke undefined behavior for most negative char values and may return incorrect results for some.  A `char` argument must be cast as `(unsigned char)` for safe operation.

Answer (score 2):

You do *not* normally want to compare the return value, just treat it as a Boolean:

```
if (isalpha(someinput))
    do_whatever();
```

If you insist on doing a comparison, it needs to be `!=0`, but it's entirely redundant and pointless.

You use it on *characters* that have been read from input, which are not (at that point) floats or anything, just groups of characters. In the case of a float, some of those will be digits, but many will also include decimal points (which aren't digits) and possibly an occasional `e`, `+` or `-` as well.

Also note that you normally need to cast the input to `unsigned char` before calling any of the `is*` functions. Many character sets will treat some characters as negative when they're viewed as `signed char`, and passing a negative value to any of these gives undefined behavior.

Comment: What if the scanned input is a number that will be used later on for calculation ?

Comment: @ZaZu: if you've already converted something to a number, there's no longer any real use for `isdigit` or `isalpha` -- it's now a number, not a digit or an alphabetic character.

Comment: How do you convert a char to a number ?

Comment: If the char is a digit, then you just subtract '0', ie: int num = ch - '0';

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for any **char** type! (actually it's int, I don't know whether this is for compatibilty reasons or whatnot, but the most common usage is for characters)

It will determine whether for example '5' is a digit or an alphanumerical (part of the alphabet). And yes, your usage is correct if `someInput` is of type "char"

Comment: Hey, no problem! That's what I'm here for!

Comment: The `isxxx()` functions are defined as taking an `int` and can be passed all values returned by `getchar()`, `getc()` and `fgetc()`, that is all values of type `unsigned char` plus the special value `EOF`, and no other.